# Выбор извлекаемых виртуальных машин

Tags: virtualbox

Требуется на хост-машине Windows развернуть несколько виртуальных. Они сохранены в одном файле VBox.ova (включая образы дисков и конфигурацию). В файле содержится 6 виртуальных машин. Ниже приведена конфигурация.

> ```
> Disks:  vmdisk1   5762867200  -1  http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized   VBox-disk1.vmdk -1  -1  
> vmdisk2   14298431488 -1  http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized   VBox-disk2.vmdk -1  -1  
> vmdisk3   16106127360 -1  http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized   VBox-disk3.vmdk -1  -1  
> vmdisk4   5368709120  -1  http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized   VBox-disk4.vmdk -1  -1  
> vmdisk5   10737418240 -1  http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized   VBox-disk5.vmdk -1  -1  
> vmdisk6   26843545600 -1  http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized   VBox-disk6.vmdk -1  -1  
> vmdisk7   10737418240 -1  http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized   VBox-disk7.vmdk -1  -1  
> vmdisk8   16106127360 -1  http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized   VBox-disk8.vmdk -1  -1  
> Virtual system 0:
>  0: Suggested OS type: "DOS"
>     (change with "--vsys 0 --ostype <type>"; use "list ostypes" to list all possible values)
>  1: Suggested VM name "DOS"
>     (change with "--vsys 0 --vmname <name>")
>  2: Number of CPUs: 1
>     (change with "--vsys 0 --cpus <n>")
>  3: Guest memory: 353 MB
>     (change with "--vsys 0 --memory <MB>")
>  4: Sound card (appliance expects "", can change on import)
>     (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 4 --ignore")
>  5: USB controller
>     (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 5 --ignore")
>  6: Network adapter: orig NAT, config 2, extra slot=0;type=NAT
>  7: Floppy
>     (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 7 --ignore")
>  8: CD-ROM
>     (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 8 --ignore")
>  9: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 9 --ignore")
> 10: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 10 --ignore")
> 11: Hard disk image: source image=VBox-disk1.vmdk, target path=D:\VBox\DOS\VBox-disk1.vmdk, controller=9;channel=0
>     (change target path with "--vsys 0 --unit 11 --disk path";
>     disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 11 --ignore")
> Virtual system 1:
>  0: Suggested OS type: "Linux"
>     (change with "--vsys 1 --ostype <type>"; use "list ostypes" to list all possible values)
>  1: Suggested VM name "Gentoo"
>     (change with "--vsys 1 --vmname <name>")
>  2: Number of CPUs: 2
>     (change with "--vsys 1 --cpus <n>")
>  3: Guest memory: 3260 MB
>     (change with "--vsys 1 --memory <MB>")
>  4: Sound card (appliance expects "", can change on import)
>     (disable with "--vsys 1 --unit 4 --ignore")
>  5: USB controller
>     (disable with "--vsys 1 --unit 5 --ignore")
>  6: Network adapter: orig NAT, config 3, extra slot=0;type=NAT
>  7: CD-ROM
>     (disable with "--vsys 1 --unit 7 --ignore")
>  8: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 1 --unit 8 --ignore")
>  9: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 1 --unit 9 --ignore")
> 10: SATA controller, type AHCI
>     (disable with "--vsys 1 --unit 10 --ignore")
> 11: Hard disk image: source image=VBox-disk2.vmdk, target path=D:\VBox\Gentoo\VBox-disk2.vmdk, controller=10;channel=0
>     (change target path with "--vsys 1 --unit 11 --disk path";
>     disable with "--vsys 1 --unit 11 --ignore")
> 12: Hard disk image: source image=VBox-disk3.vmdk, target path=D:\VBox\Gentoo\VBox-disk3.vmdk, controller=10;channel=1
>     (change target path with "--vsys 1 --unit 12 --disk path";
>     disable with "--vsys 1 --unit 12 --ignore")
> Virtual system 2:
>  0: Suggested OS type: "WindowsXP"
>     (change with "--vsys 2 --ostype <type>"; use "list ostypes" to list all possible values)
>  1: Suggested VM name "MIS_ORACLE"
>     (change with "--vsys 2 --vmname <name>")
>  2: Number of CPUs: 1
>     (change with "--vsys 2 --cpus <n>")
>  3: Guest memory: 1024 MB
>     (change with "--vsys 2 --memory <MB>")
>  4: Sound card (appliance expects "", can change on import)
>     (disable with "--vsys 2 --unit 4 --ignore")
>  5: USB controller
>     (disable with "--vsys 2 --unit 5 --ignore")
>  6: Network adapter: orig NAT, config 2, extra slot=0;type=NAT
>  7: Network adapter: orig Internal, config 2, extra slot=1;type=Internal
>  8: CD-ROM
>     (disable with "--vsys 2 --unit 8 --ignore")
>  9: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 2 --unit 9 --ignore")
> 10: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 2 --unit 10 --ignore")
> 11: Hard disk image: source image=VBox-disk4.vmdk, target path=D:\VBox\MIS_ORACLE\VBox-disk4.vmdk, controller=9;channel=0
>     (change target path with "--vsys 2 --unit 11 --disk path";
>     disable with "--vsys 2 --unit 11 --ignore")
> Virtual system 3:
>  0: Suggested OS type: "WindowsXP"
>     (change with "--vsys 3 --ostype <type>"; use "list ostypes" to list all possible values)
>  1: Suggested VM name "MUD_"
>     (change with "--vsys 3 --vmname <name>")
>  2: Number of CPUs: 1
>     (change with "--vsys 3 --cpus <n>")
>  3: Guest memory: 1881 MB
>     (change with "--vsys 3 --memory <MB>")
>  4: Sound card (appliance expects "", can change on import)
>     (disable with "--vsys 3 --unit 4 --ignore")
>  5: USB controller
>     (disable with "--vsys 3 --unit 5 --ignore")
>  6: Network adapter: orig NAT, config 2, extra slot=0;type=NAT
>  7: CD-ROM
>     (disable with "--vsys 3 --unit 7 --ignore")
>  8: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 3 --unit 8 --ignore")
>  9: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 3 --unit 9 --ignore")
> 10: Hard disk image: source image=VBox-disk5.vmdk, target path=D:\VBox\MUD_\VBox-disk5.vmdk, controller=8;channel=0
>     (change target path with "--vsys 3 --unit 10 --disk path";
>     disable with "--vsys 3 --unit 10 --ignore")
> Virtual system 4:
>  0: Suggested OS type: "Windows7"
>     (change with "--vsys 4 --ostype <type>"; use "list ostypes" to list all possible values)
>  1: Suggested VM name "Win7"
>     (change with "--vsys 4 --vmname <name>")
>  2: Number of CPUs: 4
>     (change with "--vsys 4 --cpus <n>")
>  3: Guest memory: 5216 MB
>     (change with "--vsys 4 --memory <MB>")
>  4: Sound card (appliance expects "", can change on import)
>     (disable with "--vsys 4 --unit 4 --ignore")
>  5: USB controller
>     (disable with "--vsys 4 --unit 5 --ignore")
>  6: Network adapter: orig NAT, config 3, extra slot=0;type=NAT
>  7: CD-ROM
>     (disable with "--vsys 4 --unit 7 --ignore")
>  8: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 4 --unit 8 --ignore")
>  9: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 4 --unit 9 --ignore")
> 10: SATA controller, type AHCI
>     (disable with "--vsys 4 --unit 10 --ignore")
> 11: Hard disk image: source image=VBox-disk6.vmdk, target path=D:\VBox\Win7\VBox-disk6.vmdk, controller=10;channel=0
>     (change target path with "--vsys 4 --unit 11 --disk path";
>     disable with "--vsys 4 --unit 11 --ignore")
> 12: Hard disk image: source image=VBox-disk7.vmdk, target path=D:\VBox\Win7\VBox-disk7.vmdk, controller=10;channel=1
>     (change target path with "--vsys 4 --unit 12 --disk path";
>     disable with "--vsys 4 --unit 12 --ignore")
> Virtual system 5:
>  0: Suggested OS type: "WindowsXP"
>     (change with "--vsys 5 --ostype <type>"; use "list ostypes" to list all possible values)
>  1: Suggested VM name "WinXP_SQL"
>     (change with "--vsys 5 --vmname <name>")
>  2: Number of CPUs: 1
>     (change with "--vsys 5 --cpus <n>")
>  3: Guest memory: 2048 MB
>     (change with "--vsys 5 --memory <MB>")
>  4: Sound card (appliance expects "", can change on import)
>     (disable with "--vsys 5 --unit 4 --ignore")
>  5: USB controller
>     (disable with "--vsys 5 --unit 5 --ignore")
>  6: Network adapter: orig Bridged, config 2, extra slot=1;type=Bridged
>  7: CD-ROM
>     (disable with "--vsys 5 --unit 7 --ignore")
>  8: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 5 --unit 8 --ignore")
>  9: IDE controller, type PIIX4
>     (disable with "--vsys 5 --unit 9 --ignore")
> 10: Hard disk image: source image=VBox-disk8.vmdk, target path=D:\VBox\WinXP_SQL\VBox-disk8.vmdk, controller=8;channel=0
>     (change target path with "--vsys 5 --unit 10 --disk path";
>     disable with "--vsys 5 --unit 10 --ignore")
> ```

При распаковке виртуальной машины Windows7 возникает ошибка

> Progress state: E_FAIL VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Internal inconsistency looking up disk image
>   'vmdisk6' VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005),
>   component Appliance, i nterface IAppliance VBoxManage.exe: error:
>   Context: "int __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct Handle rArg *)" at
>   line 781 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp

Эта виртуальная машина не самая необходимая, но из-за неё невозможно распаковать остальные. Пытался решить проблему так:

> D:>vboxmanage import vbox.ova --vsys 3 --vmname MUD --vsys 4 --unit 4
>   --ignore --unit 5 --ignore --unit 7 --ignore --unit 8 --ignore --unit 9 --ignore --unit 10 --ignore --unit 11 --ignore --unit 12 --ignore

То есть пытался отключить импорт этой машины. Не помогло, та же ошибка. Есть ли способ вообще отключить импорт этой машины и диска vmdisk6?

Comment: Возможно имеет смысл обновить VirtualBox до последней версии. Сталкивался с ошибками запуска виртуальных машин на ровном месте, после обновления ошибки пропадали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл с расширением ova (File Virtualization Format Archive) это архив в формате tar. Попробуйте переименуйте свой файл VBox.ova в VBox.tar и распакуйте любым архиватором который поддерживает этот формат, тот же 7zip. Дальше можно импортировать неповрежденные машины.

Comment: Да, вы правы, это помогло. Я открыл файл как архив и получил сообщение "Архив повреждён". Извлек целые файлы и из них восстановил виртуальные машины.